# How can I prevent Drupal's translation functionality from changing a menu's links?

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation

I have an about page at `/about` and a Spanish translation of the page at `/es/about`.

However, when I visit `/es/about`, the links in my main menu all have `/es` prepended to the paths.  How do I prevent this from happening, so that my main menu and its links are all exactly the same at `/es/about` as they are at `/about`?

In case it's relevant, I am printing the menu block in a template using Twig Tweak, like so:

```
{{ drupal_block('menu_block:main') }}
```

Comment: From the system’s point of view - when you’re on the Spanish site (/es), why would the menu contain links to the English site? That's traditionally a job for the language switcher. I’m only asking it like this to try to provide some early insight into why what you want to achieve might be difficult. If you’re open to other solutions (e.g. hiding untranslated menu items), the rabbit hole starts here: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2466553

Comment: For this project, from the site owner's perspective, there is no Spanish site and English site.  There is just a site, which is mainly in English, but contains perhaps a dozen or so pages translated into Spanish. Most of what is in the main menu will not be translated, and it is confusing to the user if the menu changes depending on what content the user is viewing.

Comment: If the site isn't using the more traditional approach, it might be best not to use translations to organise content. Might be best to simply re-create any "Spanish" content in the default language, and be done with it

Comment: The translation system provides a convenient way to associate the Spanish content items with the English content items in the database.  The UI (the translate tab, etc) is just what we want.  We do not want to part with most of the functionality.  Meanwhile, it's difficult to believe there really is no way to prevent a specific menu from changing depending on the language of the content item where it is displayed.  This inflexibility seems very un-Drupal-like, if true.

Comment: Not sure if this is a better way to ask my question:  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/318124/is-it-possible-with-twig-tweak-or-any-other-means-to-place-a-menu-block-in-a-s

Comment: Menus, translations, and what to display when, has been a problem in Drupal for a lonnnng time. It wouldn't surprise me if the simple thing you're asking for is actually quite difficult to reliably implement. I'd guess you'll need to write a [custom MenuLInkTree manipulator](https://www.drupal.org/node/3380509) to accomplish it

Comment: I haven't tried it but maybe it can be done by making the Menu nontranslatable (while its items are translatable), or better yet make all the items language agnostic, except the Spanish ones, that might mimic your language concept the closest.

Comment: @prkos "it can be done by making the Menu nontranslatable."  How do I do that?  That is essentially what I am asking.  How can I make a menu nontranslatable?

Comment: @prkos "make all the items language agnostic, except the Spanish ones."  What does that mean?  If it lets me control what links appear in my menus, I'm all for it.

Comment: Menu has settings you can change, if you have some modules enabled you will be able to choose whether the entire menu is translatable. You find those settings on the Menu itself, not on the list of menu items. Menu items themselves can be translatable, when you go to edit each item you can choose which language this item is using (if you have the necessary modules enabled).

Comment: @prkos "You find those settings on the Menu itself."  I don't know what you're referring to.  I don't think there's any such thing as "make all the items language agnostic".  My latest conclusion is that it isn't practical to use Drupal's multi-language functionality unless all content on the site will be translated... and that is a rare use case.